# French Canadian Cemetery: What do the initials R.I.F. stand for?

Tags: traduction

In English on gravestones one sees R.I.P.

French Canadian Cemetery gravestones use R.I.F.
What do these three initials signify?

Comment: Good question, I have seen "repose en paix" and "rest in peace" as well as the latin "requiescat in pace" and german "Ruhe in Frieden", but not noticed RIF on french graves.

Comment: I can't see any idiom in french... I'm having hard time to fill the "i"...

Comment: Maybe some word related to *fidel-*. Do you have a picture or link showing this, by the way?

Comment: Is it a military cemetery ? Could be related to "Riffles", if so.

Comment: I found a military acronym: [Régiment d'Infanterie de Forteresse](https://fr.geneawiki.com/index.php/Lexique_des_abr%C3%A9viations_militaires), in case it helps.

Comment: Are you sure that "RIF" is used in Canada? It doesn't correspond to any common phrase and I cannot find any example online, unlike "RIP" which is common.

Comment: je n'ai jamais vu « R.I.F. » sur une tombe française ou dont l'épitaphe est écrite en français. Ne pourrait-il s'agir d'un « R.I.P. », latin donc, dont le P soit abîmé ?

Comment: I've never seen that either. Do you have the region or the city where it lies and the dates on it?

Comment: @5915961T Un P gravé abîmé qui donne un F ? Un peu comme dans Astérix chez les Bretons ;)

Comment: @Mathieu Bouville – le numéro du premier cottage ? mais oui !   ; – ) Sur une autre pierre tombale, quelque part chez les Habits rouges, un pauv' artisan avait écrit sur le pan de face de la stèle funéraire : “OH LORD SHE'S THIN”, le E final était sur le pan latéral faute de place : – D  … toute la différence entre : « Seigneur ce qu'elle est maigre ! » et « Seigneur elle est à toi [désormais] » ; il n'y a pas que le latin qui soit concis, finalement ; – )

Answer (score 2):

"RIF" is certainly the abbreviation for "rifles", an army regiment.

Comment: Do you please have any sources or further details about what you're saying.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://french.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://french.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/15743)

Comment: This is an inscription that is frequently found in military cemeteries. For example, 
[the tombstones of the "Cameronians" or "Scottish Rifles".](https://rememberourdeadregimentallist.weebly.com/2nd-battalion-cameronians-scottish-rifles.html)

Answer (score 1):

Since the First World War all Canadian war graves have conformed to the standards of the Commonwealth War Graves Commission which gives the [specifications here](https://www.cwgc.org/about-us/faqs#howwecommemorate).

There are four elements.

> Regimental symbol.
>   Name, rank and regiment.
>   Religious symbol.
>   Optional text chosen by the family.

If the RIF is in section 2 then the only explanation is that it is part of the name of a RIFle regiment.

If it is in section 4 then it is up to the family so it will not be a general feature of Canadian graves. However, some sort of error for RIP does seem likely.